# How to allow iPhone auto lock when the app is installed using xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I need to prevent the phone from auto-lock on one page of the app. I found [an IONIC plugin for this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/insomnia). I want to make sure it works. The problem is: when I run the app on a device or simulator, the auto-lock is not happening at all.

That's how I run the app on the iOs device:

- `ionic cordova run ios --device`
- open `platforms/ios` in the code
- select the device and press the play button

The app is installed and I can play with it. The auto-lock is not happening while the app is opened.

I tried to remove the cable after the app installation with no success. If my app is opened, the lock screen is not displayed.

So, how can I allow the phone to auto-lock while development time?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `debug` option in the architecture section of the project helped. need to unplug the device anyway.